# How to automatically extract satellite images from a list of coordinates

Tags: python, api, satellite

I have a dataframe composed of 4000 lines of geographic coordinates of various types of infrastructures. I mainly work on Python.

From each of theses coordinates I would like to automatically extract satellite images (square 2*2km - jpeg format) of the infrastructure.
I’m new in the domain and I would like to know if an API exists (with free access) which is able to extract this amount of information and also if a specific python code exists to obtain such a result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python API for Google Earth Engine.  [See this link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/intro-to-python-api).